# FIXED: Wordpress site Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).live is not a function causing images with JS to not show

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am building a WordPress site and suddenly am getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).live is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js?ver=1.1:214)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
```

I am unsure how to replicate this error as it is a sudden occurrence.

When I visit my site no images are loading which have JS

I have checked my plugins and don't seem to see anything new added when I view the site in Elementor all images are showing, any ideas of how to fix this? None of this site has been raw coded just pure WordPress

Can anyone inspect element and tell me if/what plugin is causing me issues?

Comment: Wordpress 5.5 stopped using jquery migrate. It's been causing problems with old plugins and themes. This might fix it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/

Comment: @Cully Thank you, has this change happened within the last day or so?

Comment: @Cully Thank you this helped! Are you able to post as an answer so I can select in case anyone else in the community runs into the same problem, please :)

Comment: I posted a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Wordpress 5.5 stopped using jQuery migrate](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/wordpress-5-5-issues/). This change has been causing problems with old plugins and themes. If you are noticing issues after upgrading to Wordpress 5.5, installing this plugin might fix it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/

Though, ultimately a better solution would be to either upgrade your current plugins and themes to versions that do not rely on jQuery migrate. Or, if that is not possible, try to move away from those plugins to ones that do not require jQuery migrate. If you don't, you will likely run into compatibility issues in the future or, even worse, security vulnerabilities from these outdated plugins/themes.

**UPDATE: Sep 18, 2020**

I looked at the source code for the Enable jQuery Migrate Helper plugin and it has this condition for running:

```php
if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '5.6-alpha', '<' ) && ! class_exists( 'jQuery_Migrate_Helper' ) ) {
    include_once __DIR__ . '/class-jquery-migrate-helper.php';
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'jQuery_Migrate_Helper', 'init_actions' ) );
}
```

So, the plugin will only work up to, and including, Wordpress 5.5. Once Wordpress hits version 5.6-alpha, it will stop working.

**UPDATE: Feb 15, 2021**

The plugin code has been updated to work past Wordpress 5.6. However, at and after version 5.6, it will include `jquery-migrate-3.3.2` instead of `jquery-migrate-1.4.1` and it includes a lot fewer files (mostly jquery-ui scripts). If you want to continue using the older version of jquery, there are a couple options.

**Option A.** You could copy the jquery migrate plugin to a new folder (basically make it your own plugin), rename it, edit the `class-jquery-migrate-helper.php` file, find this line in the `replace_scripts` function:

```php
if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '5.6-alpha', '<' ) || 'yes' === get_option( '_jquery_migrate_downgrade_version', 'no' ) ) {
```

And replace it with:

```php
if(true) {
```

This will cause the plugin to always install the old version of jquery.

**Option B.** Create a new plugin that just includes the old jquery files by doing the following:

1. Create a new plugin.
2. Copy all of the `enable-jquery-migrate-helper/js` files from the jquery migrate plugin to the `js/` folder in your new plugin.
3. Add this code to your plugin file:

```php
add_action('wp_default_scripts', function ($scripts) {
    $setScripts = function($scripts, $handle, $src, $deps = [], $ver = false, $in_footer = false) {
        $script = $scripts->query( $handle, 'registered' );

        if ( $script ) {
            // If already added
            $script->src  = $src;
            $script->deps = $deps;
            $script->ver  = $ver;
            $script->args = $in_footer;

            unset( $script->extra['group'] );

            if ( $in_footer ) {
                $script->add_data( 'group', 1 );
            }
        } else {
            // Add the script
            if ( $in_footer ) {
                $scripts->add( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, 1 );
            } else {
                $scripts->add( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver );
            }
        }
    };

    $assets_url = $assets_url = plugins_url( 'js/', __FILE__  );

    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-migrate', $assets_url . 'jquery-migrate/jquery-migrate-1.4.1-wp.js', array(), '1.4.1-wp' );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-core', $assets_url . 'jquery/jquery-1.12.4-wp.js', array(), '1.12.4-wp' );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core', 'jquery-migrate' ), '1.12.4-wp' );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-core', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/core.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-effects-core', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/effect.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-effects-blind', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/effect-blind.min.js', array( 'jquery-effects-core' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-effects-bounce', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/effect-bounce.min.js', array( 'jquery-effects-core' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-effects-clip', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/effect-clip.min.js', array( 'jquery-effects-core' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-effects-drop', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/effect-drop.min.js', array( 'jquery-effects-core' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-effects-explode', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/effect-explode.min.js', array( 'jquery-effects-core' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-effects-fade', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/effect-fade.min.js', array( 'jquery-effects-core' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-effects-fold', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/effect-fold.min.js', array( 'jquery-effects-core' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-effects-highlight', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/effect-highlight.min.js', array( 'jquery-effects-core' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-effects-puff', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/effect-puff.min.js', array( 'jquery-effects-core', 'jquery-effects-scale' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-effects-pulsate', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/effect-pulsate.min.js', array( 'jquery-effects-core' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-effects-scale', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/effect-scale.min.js', array( 'jquery-effects-core', 'jquery-effects-size' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-effects-shake', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/effect-shake.min.js', array( 'jquery-effects-core' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-effects-size', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/effect-size.min.js', array( 'jquery-effects-core' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-effects-slide', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/effect-slide.min.js', array( 'jquery-effects-core' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-effects-transfer', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/effect-transfer.min.js', array( 'jquery-effects-core' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-accordion', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/accordion.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-widget' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-autocomplete', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/autocomplete.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-menu', 'wp-a11y' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-button', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/button.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-widget' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-datepicker', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/datepicker.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-core' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-dialog', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/dialog.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-resizable', 'jquery-ui-draggable', 'jquery-ui-button', 'jquery-ui-position' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-draggable', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/draggable.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-mouse' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-droppable', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/droppable.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-draggable' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-menu', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/menu.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-widget', 'jquery-ui-position' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-mouse', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/mouse.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-widget' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-position', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/position.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-progressbar', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/progressbar.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-widget' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-resizable', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/resizable.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-mouse' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-selectable', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/selectable.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-mouse' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-selectmenu', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/selectmenu.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-menu' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-slider', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/slider.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-mouse' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-sortable', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/sortable.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-mouse' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-spinner', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/spinner.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-button' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-tabs', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/tabs.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-widget' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-tooltip', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/tooltip.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-widget', 'jquery-ui-position' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-ui-widget', $assets_url . 'jquery-ui/widget.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.11.4-wp', 1 );
    $setScripts( $scripts, 'jquery-touch-punch', false, array( 'jquery-ui-widget', 'jquery-ui-mouse' ), '0.2.2', 1 );
}, -10);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I appreciate your help

Comment: The function didn't work for me in a child-theme. I had to add the script itself in the footer: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: "You could copy the jquery migrate plugin to a new folder" how do you do that?

Comment: @CodyBugstein Copy the contents of the jquery migrate plugin to a new folder with a different name. It's essentially like creating a new plugin with the same code, except for the one change I described.

Comment: How do you copy it to a new folder, is what I'm asking

Comment: @CodyBugstein In linux or macos, you could do `cp -R folderA folderB`. In windows just copy/paste in explorer.

Comment: @CodyBugstein Just basic file copy ^^^

Answer (score 5):

Wordpress 5.5 stopped using jquery migrate. It's been causing problems with old plugins and themes. This is the fix: https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/

Comment: This isn't a solution

Comment: @CodyBugstein This was a temporary fix Cully further elaborated above

Comment: Well it temporarily solved my Case. Confirmed for Wordpress 5.7. Avada Theme: Caused Problems switching Tabs in the Fusion Builder

Comment: It's more a flash fix so you can keep your website running until a permanent resolution was delivered (Theme devs update to support).