# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function ERROR (with wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, typeerror

I'm trying to link my javascript to a module on wordpress. I linked it with wp_register_script and wp_enqueue_script, but I am finding an error called "uncaught typeError: $ is not a function ERROR." I have my code listed first, and then what I have tried at the bottom.
`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
        direction: 'horizontal',
        loop: false,
        allowTouchMove: true,
        slidesPerGroup: 1,
        
        //Responsive Breakpoints
        breakpoints: {
            1700: {
                slidesPerView: 5,
                spaceBetween: 20,
            },
            960: {
                slidesPerView: 3,
                spaceBetween: 13,
            },
            730: {
                slidesPerView: 2,
                spaceBetween: 13,
            },
            550: {
                slidesPerView: 2,
                spaceBetween: 13,
            },
            1: {
                slidesPerView: 1,
                spaceBetween: 13,
            }
        },

        // Navigation arrows
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            disabledClass: 'disabled_swiper_button'
        },
    });
});
```

`

and my scripts.php file
`

```
<?php


function hunter_scripts () {
    // Register styles and scripts
    wp_register_style( 'hunterpanels', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), _S_VERSION );

    wp_register_script( 'hunterpanels-nav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/nav.js', array('jquery'), null, false );
    wp_register_style( 'material-icons', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' );

    wp_register_script( 'hunterpanels-image-carousel-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/image-carousel.js', array('jquery'), null, false );
    wp_register_style( 'hunterpanels-image-carousel-js', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' );

    
    // Enqueue styles and scripts
    wp_enqueue_style( 'hunterpanels', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), _S_VERSION );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'hunterpanels-nav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/nav.js', array('jquery'), null, false );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'material-icons', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'hunterpanels-image-carousel-js' );
    


    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hunter_scripts' );
?>
```

`

full error message:

`

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.2
image-carousel.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at image-carousel.js:1:1
(anonymous) @ image-carousel.js:1
```

`

I tried replacing `$` with `jquery` in the javascript file, but it did not change. I tried the top answer on this post, but it did not change. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63481440/fixed-wordpress-site-uncaught-typeerror-jquery-live-is-not-a-function-cau)

I tried option A and B. Neither of them worked.

I also installed the Enable jQuery Migrate Helper plugin, but it didn't work.

Comment: ``$ is not a function`` sounds like the jquery library is missing...